# "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'description' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel and trying to build a gallery, i'm testing the upload of a file to a db but i when i click submit i get the error 
" Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000)
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column

I've set up a GalleryController and the code is as follows

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;

class GalleryController extends Controller
{
    // List Galleries
    public function index (){
            //Render View
        return view ('gallery/index');
    }

    // Show Create From
    public function create(){
            //Render View
        return view ('gallery/create');
    }

    // Store Gallery
    public function store(Request $request){
            // Get Request Input
        $name = $request->input ('name');
        $description = $request->input ('description');
        $cover_image = $request->input ('cover_image');
        $owner_id = 1;

        // Check Image Upload
        if($cover_image){
            $cover_image_filename = $cover_image->getClientOriginalName();
            $cover_image->move(public_path('images'), $cover_image_filename);
        } else {
            $cover_image_filename = 'noimage.jpg';
        }

        //Insert Gallery
        DB::table('galleries')->insert(
        [
            'name'          => $name,
            'description'   => $description,
            'cover_image'   => $cover_image,
            'owner_id'      => $owner_id,

        ]
        );

        //Redirect
        return \Redirect::route('gallery.index')-> with('message', 'Gallery Created');
    }


    //Show Gallery Photos 
    public function show($id){
            die ($id);
```

`

The main.blade.php calls the code using

```
@ if(Session::has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-info">
{{Session::get('message')}}
</div>
@ endif;
```

My .env DB is set to root and password is blank too.

If any more info is needed please advise.

Thanks

Comment: are you added the description in fillable

Comment: `$request->input ('description');` is empty. Either there's no input named `description`, or it's empty. You can change it to `$request->input ('description', '');` so that it will automatically fill in with an empty string, or you can use a validation to make sure the description is filled in.

Comment: Show your migration for that table. By the way, you're not specifying the value for `description`, so you get an error. Try `dd($request->input)` and check if description is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two error:
1) description be null because fo your input was come null or in your view file it has another name
you may do this set default value?

```
$description = ($request->input ('description')) ? $request->input('description'): "description";
```

2) your second error is you save temporary image file name
use this instead

//Insert Gallery

```
DB::table('galleries')->insert(
    [
        'name'          => $name,
        'description'   => $description,
        'cover_image'   => $cover_image_filename,
        'owner_id'      => $owner_id,

    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it both of the suggestions you made have resolved my issue.